# Is there a 2d animation authoring GUI for creating C++ games?

Tags: c++, flash, animation

I'm moving from Flash to C++, and am wondering if there are any tools out there that would let me author animation much like Flash does.

Basically I want a GUI that lets me layout sprites and specify keyframes + easing for position, size, rotation, etc., then later be able to load and play these animations from my own code.

I've found a couple promising projects for UI interface animation, but I suspect since they're built for UI they're not optimized for game playback.

I've also found a bunch of animation libraries, but nothing that also provides a GUI for creating the animations.

Being able to animate textures would also be a plus.

Answer (score 2):

[Torque 2D](http://www.garagegames.com/products/torque-2d) is the only such I've heard of for C++ development, and I am not sure it offers anything like Flash's level of control in terms of timeline animation. Other paid solutions may offer similar. But in general, you'll find that C++ doesn't do a magical all-in-one the way Flash does, i.e. executable and resources all nicely packaged up into one file from the same single development environment. Once you move into the world of C++, building custom tools is going to become a necessary part of developing your games.

As for ease of coding, its not going to be as simple to integrate with the resources, although Allegro, Torque2D, HGE and others may at least provide the sort of 2D game-related foundations you're looking for in terms of their codebases, such as resource loading,  animation etc.

If you don't have your sights solidly set on C++, you may want to look into Unity. It can be pretty expensive, but you can use it for free. It has an excellent IDE, and I understand it has timeline functionality.

As for texture animation, the best I could suggest would be something like Cosmigo Pro-Motion, Allegro Sprite Editor or Pixen (Mac only) that are built for pixelling and (2D) sprite animation.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I think I'm going to try using SVG; I just learned SVG is capable of animation and there are plenty of libraries and authoring tools out there. since most of my sprites will just be simple bitmap fills I don't think there will be too much overhead.

Comment: @mayobutter: So how are you going to render that SVG? Most SVG renderers ignore SVG animation, since SVG is primarily used for images, not animations. Are you planning to run your game in a web-browser?

Comment: Tried animated SVG in FF; it worked. So I looked into what SVG library FF uses and found Cairo (I could be wrong). Now I'm downloading all the tools to hook everything up; who knows if it'll actually work or not :)

Comment: @nick-wiggill what are the paid solution?

Comment: @mayobutter Let us know. What I've heard is that the SVG standard is horrific to work with, so if Cairo doesn't support what you need, another solution may be required.

Comment: @iamcreasy, I only said, "Other paid solutions *may* offer similar". Generally it's only when a company sells their engine, that they can also afford to develop a fully-fledged IDE. Such is the case with Torque, Unity and UDK, for instance. I know of only one such free solution (for Java), called JMonkeyEngine, for which they are developing an IDE that supports content design.